# Axis Labels for Ridge Trace Plot

Tags: plot

I am trying to customize the axis labels for a ridge trace plot but the labels aren't showing up when I compile. How do I get these labels to work?

```
\begin{center}
  <<fig=TRUE,echo=FALSE,width=5,height=3>>=
  plot(ridge,main="blah",xlab="lambda",floating=F)
  abline(v=6.5)
  abline(v=11)
  abline(v=15)
  @
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.